# The package name "apzentral/ink" is invalid

Tags: composer-php

When I go to https://packagist.org/packages/submit to submit my package.

This error is shown,

```
The package name apzentral/ink is invalid, it should have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name. The vendor and package name can be words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match "[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*".
```

I would like to know what is wrong in my git repository setup.

Here is the link to go to [my repository](https://github.com/apzentral/ink)

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at your `composer.json` file, you'll see:

```
"name": " apzentral/ink",
```

Do you notice the space before the package name? That's what causing the failure (a space is not valid in a package name)

```
"name": "apzentral/ink"
```

Comment: Thanks, pointed me in the right direction. I had a capital letter in my name, this is invalid in Packagist.

Answer (score 2):

If you're here and if you **don't have any issues in the package name** in composer.json, probably you may want to check your composer version. I was using Composer version `2.0.11`. Once I downgraded it to `1.6.3`, it worked smoothly.

Comment: this create more q, why downgrade solving it?

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo valid question, but don't have an answer yet. also, appears that the above trick is _not_ working now